# Passing in parameter to Styled Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, styled-components

How can I pass in an argument into Styled Components?

What I tried was to create an interface and a styled component:

```
export interface StyledContainerProps {
  topValue?: number;
}

export const StyledContainer: StyledComponentClass<StyledContainerProps> = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  top: `${props.topValue || 0}px`;
`;
```

Then I want to use it like this:

```
<StyledContainer 
  topValue={123}
>
   This has a distance of 123px to the top
</StyledContainer>
```

But it's saying that `props` doesn't have the attribute `topValue`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Actually you should receive `cannot read property 'topValue' of undefined` error.

Use a function insead:

```
const StyledContainer = styled.div<{ topValue: number }>`
    top: ${({ topValue = 0 }) => topValue}px;
`;
```

Also a little bonus - you can use argument destructuring and assign a default value for `topValue` if it doesn't exist (in your particular case - the default value would be `0`).

However if you want to assign `0` in every case when `topValue` is falsy, use:

```
const StyledContainer = styled.div<{ topValue: number }>`
    top: ${(props) => props.topValue || 0}px;
`;
```

**Note**: Doubled backticks are redundant.

Comment: It seems like the custom value `123` didn't get passed through but the default value was accepted.

Comment: @thadeuszlay It's not possible, actually :) If it doesn't work for you, just use `||`.

Answer (score 16):

You can pass an argument with Typescript as follows:

```
<StyledPaper open={open} />    

...

const StyledPaper = styled(Paper)<{ open: boolean }>`
   top: ${p => (p.open ? 0 : 100)}%;
`;
```

Comment: The type `Paper` makes this a bit more confusing I think, if you just replaced `Paper` with `div` would this work?

Comment: I used `Paper` on purpose to make an example with a custom component. With a `div` would it work if you use `styled.div<{ open: boolean }>` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume you have a component that is called `Avatar` and you need to pass a boolean prop to decide the size of the conponent (40 or 80 pixels).

You define the styled component as follows:

```
export const UserAvatar = styled(Avatar)`
   height: ${props => (props.large ? 80 : 40)}px;
   width:  ${props => (props.large ? 80 : 40)}px;
`;
```

And you use it like this: `<UserAvatar large="true" />`